# How to run unittest in a flask project?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am reading "Flask Web Development", published by o'reilly. At chapter 7, the author shows that the basic structure is like:

```
|-app/
|-tests/
   |-__init__.py
   |-test_basics.py
|-manage.py
|-config.py
```

And the test_basics.py shows that

```
from app import create_app
```

I wonder how it works to import app when test_basics is not at the same level as app package?

And what is the way to invoke the test_basics? By "python test_basics.py" or using "python manage.py test" and pass the app as a parameter to test_basics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example project for the book, you can run the unit tests from the root project directory with the following command:

```
python manage.py test
```

The `from app import create_app` statement works because imports are not relative, they are evaluated from the current directory. If you wanted to use a relative import you would add a dot before the module name.